# Using jquery post in liferay portlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, liferay, portlet

I want to use `jquery` in my portlet, but its my first portlet and dont know what needs to be done.

I am setting parameters in `view.jsp` and doing something like this:

```
<portlet: actionURL var="setStatusURL">
    <portlet: param name="jspPage" var="/setStatus.jsp"/>
</portlet: actionURL>

$.post(
   "<%=setStatusURL %>",
   {
       ids:ch.toString()
   }
);
```

`Firebug` says that `setStatus.jsp 404 not found`.

How should I write the URL so that this works correctly?

Comment: Well, it just need to be the right URL...

Comment: Sorry my english is terrible. U mean that there no any mistakes?

Comment: After redeploy in firebug i see that perametrs was sended in setStatus.jsp but nothing heppens. In setStatus.jsp java code is corect couse when i use it in simple web project it works fine. but in eclipse i see a error on line "<%=setStatusURL %>", setStatusURL cannot be resolved as variable.

Comment: you have put var="/setStatus.jsp" and it should be value="/setStatus.jsp" Also from the above snippet I am assuming setStatus.jsp is in docroot folder

Comment: Sorry , im have a mistake here, in code i write value="/setStatus.jsp". I dont understand why you say about docroot? I   have to put setStatus.jsp in another directory?

Comment: maybe i have to say about my problem alot. I want to send parametrs in setStatus.jsp from view.jsp. In setStatus.jsp i connect to PosrtgreSql and work with tables. Now wat i have. In FireBug in POST tab i see that my parametrs was sended, but in Answer tab i see a code of LifeaRay page. Its mean that setStatus.jsp dont work and i gat view.jsp immediately. i try gat some test parametrs from setStatus.jsp but in alert get just html cod of view.jsp.

Comment: WHY WHY for jsp work i must use  <portlet: actionURL? Why not actionURL? I was thought that renderURL used for showing jsp page. Any way thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is an ajax call, I would think the URL should be generated using `ResourceURL` ([`<portlet:resourceURL />`](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/sdk_portletcontaineru5/#Resource_Serving)) instead of `<portlet:actionURL />`.

Also it is obvious that you would need to explicitly include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library in your portlet to use it. Since Liferay 6.0, jQuery is removed as an inbuilt javascript library.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: please ensure that all the required js files configured.
Step 2: make use of your action url properly in script providing area (jquery)
Step 3: follow jquery script syntax

Comment: 1 i add jquery.js in liferay-portlet.xml but eclipse says that there some errors in this library, but when i use this library in simle html all was fine. 2 U mean that i gonna write all this syntax <portlet: actionURL var="setStatusURL">
<portlet: param name="jspPage" var="/setStatus.jsp"/>
</portlet: actionURL> inside post? 3 u see any mistakes in my syntax?

Comment: Generally how we are access the action url is form action="<%=setStatusURL.toString()" method="post"> </form>